# Sending bufs with 'MSG_ZEROCOPY' flag and 'SO_ZEROCOPY' option in kernel 4.14 behaves worse than non_zerocpy

Tags: c, linux, caching, linux-kernel, zero-copy

I have a try on zero_copy of kernel 4.14, follow is the details about zero_copy in kernel 4.14.

[1] (https://netdevconf.org/2.1/papers/netdev.pdf)

And I test it in squid which is a cache proxy.My code is a little diffrent with above. I use epoll to handle zerocopy and copy disk file to send to the client.
When the socket is writable, I use function as follow

```
send(fd, buf, sz, MSG_ZEROCOPY); //sz=16KB, 32KB
```

Also I handle EPOLLERR as follow to free the buf allocated.

```
recvmsg(fd, &msg, MSG_ERRQUEUE)
```

But I found that the fd is often waked up with EPOLLERR, SO I call recvmsg after every send calls or else the cpu runs very high. Then I use curl to make requests to the squid proxy which has caches for the request.

```
foreach -c 400 -w 4 'curl -o /dev/null -s -w "%{time_connect} %{time_total} %{speed_download}\n" http://160MB.html -x 192.168.1.20:3128 -H "Pragma: "'
```

But the result shows that 
non_zero_copy code is more quickly. And the cpu hot functions distributes as follow:

```
non_zero_copy: %Cpu1  : 21.9 us, 77.1 sy,  0.0 ni,  0.7 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.3 st 

   32.52%  [kernel]             [k] copy_user_enhanced_fast_string
   8.73%  libc-2.17.so         [.] __memcpy_ssse3_back
   6.36%  [kernel]             [k] iowrite16
   3.97%  [kernel]             [k] do_syscall_64
   3.60%  [kernel]             [k] _raw_spin_unlock_irqrestore
   3.25%  libc-2.17.so         [.] __memset_sse2
   2.74%  [kernel]             [k] find_get_entry
   2.03%  libpthread-2.17.so   [.] pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2
   1.66%  [kernel]             [k] tcp_sendmsg_locked
   1.44%  [kernel]             [k] generic_file_read_iter
   0.84%  [kernel]             [k] finish_task_switch
   0.80%  libc-2.17.so         [.] epoll_ctl
   0.78%  [kernel]             [k] __fget
   0.78%  [kernel]             [k] get_page_from_freelist
   0.77%  [kernel]             [k] sock_poll
   0.71%  [kernel]             [k] skb_release_data
   0.69%  libpthread-2.17.so   [.] __pthread_disable_asynccancel
   0.64%  [kernel]             [k] sys_epoll_ctl
   0.62%  [kernel]             [k] __audit_syscall_exit

zero_copy: %Cpu1  : 35.8 us, 63.9 sy,  0.0 ni,  0.3 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st

   9.41%  [kernel]             [k] do_syscall_64
   8.57%  [kernel]             [k] copy_user_enhanced_fast_string
   7.79%  [kernel]             [k] _raw_spin_unlock_irqrestore
   7.55%  libc-2.17.so         [.] 0x00000000000f7d13
   6.70%  [kernel]             [k] ep_send_events_proc
   5.11%  [vdso]               [.] __vdso_gettimeofday
   4.73%  libc-2.17.so         [.] __memset_sse2
   4.16%  [kernel]             [k] pvclock_clocksource_read
   3.66%  libc-2.17.so         [.] __memcpy_ssse3_back
   2.02%  [kernel]             [k] tcp_poll
   1.95%  [kernel]             [k] iowrite16
   1.93%  squid                [.] comm_select
   1.73%  [kernel]             [k] find_get_entry
   1.57%  [kernel]             [k] sock_poll
   1.54%  [kernel]             [k] __fget
   1.53%  [kernel]             [k] select_estimate_accuracy
   1.41%  squid                [.] getCurrentTime
   0.86%  [kernel]             [k] ktime_get_ts64
   0.84%  [kernel]             [k] ep_poll
   0.83%  [kernel]             [k] ep_scan_ready_list.isra.13
   0.81%  libpthread-2.17.so   [.] pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2
   0.73%  [kernel]             [k] fput
   0.71%  [kernel]             [k] __audit_syscall_entry
   0.71%  [kernel]             [k] __audit_syscall_exit
   0.70%  [kernel]             [k] mutex_lock
   0.66%  [kernel]             [k] _raw_spin_lock_irqsave
   0.59%  libc-2.17.so         [.] __libc_disable_asynccancel
   0.57%  squid                [.] statHistCount
```

Does anyone have the same test with me? And why my test is not same with the result of the article in pdf above.

Comment: Hi can you please elaborate the steps followed by you to test MSG_ZERO copy.., im trying to test the same, i'm getting an error as given below
exec of "./msg_zerocopy" failed: No such file or directory
[1]+  Exit 1                  ip netns exec cli "${BIN}" "-${IP}" -i p4p4 -t 2 -C 2 -S "${SADDR}" -D "${DADDR}" ${ARGS} -r "${RXMODE}"

Comment: I don't test msg_zerocopy in the kernel's example, but use the functions at squid source code

Answer (score 4):

Are you trying zerocopy over loopback or real network card? Be sure to check Documentation/networking/msg_zerocopy.rst first

> ### Loopback
>
> Data sent to local sockets can be queued indefinitely if the receive
>   process does not read its socket. Unbound notification latency is not 
>   acceptable. For this reason all packets generated with MSG_ZEROCOPY
>   that are looped to a local socket will incur a deferred copy. This
>   includes looping onto packet sockets (e.g., tcpdump) and tun devices.

Also, looking at the implementation, it seems that your network card must have enabled tx-scatter-gather-fraglist. Check it in `ethtool -k`.

```
   zc = sk->sk_route_caps & NETIF_F_SG;
    if (!zc)
      uarg->zerocopy = 0; 

enum {
  NETIF_F_SG_BIT,     /* Scatter/gather IO. */
```

Comment: thanks ,you are right .  I test in a virtual machine,when i move test to a real machine, i can get correct result. And also the function stack is associated with ”zero_copy“ ，but in virtual machine the function stack is not associated with "zero_copy"

Comment: I test request from 192.168.1.70 to 192.168.1.20 ,the two virtual machine is on a same real machine. 
but the option tx-scatter-gather-fraglist is off (fixed)

Answer (score 1):

I modify nothing just move tests from virtual machine to real machine: the function __zerocopy_sg_from_iter which never occured in the virtual machine but in the real machine.

```
ZERO_COPY: (in real machine)
%Cpu1  : 17.8 us, 34.9 sy,  0.0 ni, 47.3 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
13903 squid     20   0  147236  45196   5860 R  52.2  0.1   0:15.65 squid  

  18.42%  libc-2.17.so         [.] __memcpy_ssse3_back
  17.32%  [kernel]             [k] copy_user_generic_string
   2.79%  [kernel]             [k] syscall_return_via_sysret
   2.09%  [unknown]            [k] 0xfffffe800003201e
   1.91%  [kernel]             [k] gup_pgd_range
   1.21%  [kernel]             [k] generic_file_read_iter
   1.20%  [kernel]             [k] _raw_spin_lock
   1.05%  [kernel]             [k] sock_poll
   1.04%  [kernel]             [k] sys_epoll_ctl
   1.02%  [kernel]             [k] __schedule
   0.97%  [kernel]             [k] __audit_syscall_entry
   0.93%  [kernel]             [k] __zerocopy_sg_from_iter

and i make a comparisonwith NO_ZEROCOPY in real machine
%Cpu1  : 11.4 us, 46.8 sy,  0.0 ni, 41.8 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st                                                                                                                 
13988 squid     20   0  115948  15228   5784 R  57.5  0.0   0:31.99 squid
   33.27%  [kernel]             [k] copy_user_generic_string
   9.62%  libc-2.17.so         [.] __memcpy_ssse3_back
   2.34%  [kernel]             [k] syscall_return_via_sysret
   1.80%  [unknown]            [k] 0xfffffe800003201e
   1.35%  [kernel]             [k] tcp_sendmsg_locked
   1.18%  [kernel]             [k] generic_file_read_iter 
    NO_ZEROCOPY    ZERO_COPY
cpu 62.9           53.6
cpu 53.6           43.3
cpu 46.8           34.9
```